# Small 3D Scene Graph

Tags: graphics, scene-graph

I'm looking for a 3D graphics library (not a complete game engine). Preferred a **scene graph**. **Something small** (unlike jME, XNA or Unity), that I can easily expand and change.

Preferred features:

- Cross Platform
- Wrriten in Java/Scala (JOGL or LWJGL), C# (preferred OpenTK), Python or JavaScript/WebGL.
- Support for OpenGL is a must. Direct3D is optional.
- Some material system
- Full support for some model format with full animation support (preferred COLLADA)
- Level of Detail (LOD) support
- Lighting support
- Shaders, GUI, Input and Terrain/Water support are also preferred, but not required

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/).

- Cross platform ( All desktop OSes )
- Python API ( although the core is written in C++ )
- OpenGL support
- At least I'm sure you can import models from Blender (there's a Blender plugin for that)
- shaders, HUD, input, and whatnot
- and it's open source (meaning that you can expand it)

Answer (score 2):

**[Xith3D](http://xith.org/)**

- Cross Platform - **Yes (java)**
- Wrriten in Java/Scala (JOGL or LWJGL), C# (preferred OpenTK), Python or JavaScript/WebGL. - **Yes (java)**
- Support for OpenGL is a must. Direct3D is optional. - **Yes (java)**
- Some material system- **Yes (java)**
- Full support for some model format with full animation support (preferred COLLADA)- **Yes (.obj,.md2,.md3,.md5,.dae (somewhat), .ase,.3ds, and others)**
- Level of Detail (LOD) support - **Yes**
- Lighting support- **Yes**
- Shaders, GUI, Input and Terrain/Water support are also preferred, but not required - **Yes (no multipass shaders, but otherwise good enough; terrain system does exist; GUI is there and easy to use)**

Xith3D is a useful Java-based engine in the spirit of Java3D, but with a lot of the crazy and overengineering removed. The community is helpful, and the documentation is a lot better than I've seen for similar projects. Tutorials exist and are succinct.

Answer (score 0):

### [Ogre4J](http://ogre4j.sourceforge.net/)

- Cross Platform - **Yes**
- Written in Java
- Support for OpenGL is a must. Direct3D is optional. - **Both**
- Some material system - **Yes**
- Full support for some model format with full animation support (preferred COLLADA) - Ogre animations which has exports for Maya and 3d Studio Max
- Level of Detail (LOD) support - **Yes**
- Lighting support - **Yes**
- Shaders, GUI, Input and Terrain/Water support are also preferred, but not required - **Yes**

Ogre4J is a binding to the Ogre C++ graphics renderer.  Going straight to C++ is probably preferred though.

Ogre is a scene graph based rendering engine which does everything you're looking for.